# Providing EXIF-free images in a gallery or other webpage

Tags: metadata, exif

First, thanks for any and all help regarding this topic.

Sites like Facebook and Twitter strip EXIF information from images as they are uploading. My goal is to allow users to upload images to our platform (working with Nextcloud and others) with full EXIF information, however, we need to display images that do not contain EXIF information or any metadata.  Without stripping and creating a second, Exif-Free image for each, is it possible to simply hide that EXIF info so that, if a user downloads that image, the EXIF is not embedded?

We were told that the only way to do this is to have a second, exif-free copy (the order of when that's created is irrelevant pre/during/post upload).  I'm hoping there's a way that we can simply display such a copy without doubling our physical space requirements.

Thanks again for your help.

Answer (score 2):

[Exif](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exif) **is** metadata, along with [IPTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPTC), [XMP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extensible_Metadata_Platform), [AFCP](http://fileformats.archiveteam.org/wiki/AFCP), [ICC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ICC_profile), [FPXR](https://exiftool.org/TagNames/FlashPix.html), [MPF](https://web.archive.org/web/20190713230858/http://www.cipa.jp/std/documents/e/DC-007_E.pdf), [JPS](http://fileformats.archiveteam.org/wiki/JPS) and a comment, just for the [JFIF/JPEG file format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JPEG_File_Interchange_Format) alone. Other picture file formats support even more/other metadata.

You wrote it yourself: a *download* - so it's a file in any case. Pictures are files, just like executables, movies, texts, music and archives are files, too. And metadata is part of its content, so whoever accesses the raw bytes of the file can grab everything in it. Which is not "*please don't look*" proof. If you

- create that on the fly by stripping metadata everytime a download is requested,
- or if you do it once to preserve performance and instead occupy space remains your decision.

If there would be something as simple as a "*don't show*" feature then it would still be in the file and could be extracted easily by software written to ignore that instruction. Seriously, there's no shortcut to that - do it properly and don't spare yourself from getting work done at the wrong end.

Comment: Thank you.  This all makes sense.
I suppose the only proper way to do it is to create a second, stripped version for performance reasons.

Answer (score 0):

mod_magick_strip will do this for you, as part of mod_magick.

The MAGICK filter parses the image, the MAGICK_STRIP filter strips the metadata.

https://github.com/minfrin/mod_magick

```
<FilesMatch ".+\.(gif|jpe?g|png)$">
  SetOutputFilter MAGICK;MAGICK_STRIP
</FilesMatch>
```

(I wrote this a number of years ago)